# Proof that the divergence is the limit of the ratio of the surface integral and the volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, divergence-theorem

Let us assume that I have a series of compact smooth sets $A_n$ that converges to the set with a single point $\{x\}$. For any given $\epsilon$ there is an index in the sequence from which on all the sets are in the open neighbourhood of $x$ of size $\epsilon$. I am currently working on a proof that the divergence in a point for the function $F$, which is continuously differentiable, is the limit of the the divergence on the surface of $A_n$ divided by the volume of $A_n$. I tried to model $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda^d (A_n)^{-1} \int_{A_n} div F(x) d \lambda^d (x)$ as a difference quotient, but that does not seem to work out because then I would have infinitly-dimensional function (taking a set and yielding a scalar). Does anybody have a hint how I could continue?

Comment: Oh yes, I should have said that as well. The series of smooth sets are for any given epsilon at some point in the open neighbourhood of x.

Comment: Assuming enough regularity that it makes sense, the correct result is the divergence theorem: the integral of the divergence over $A_n$ is the flux out of $A_n$. As you collapse $A_n$ to one point, the divergence goes to one number, so the flux goes to the divergence at $x$ times the volume of $A_n$. Thus the divergence at $x$ is the limit of the flux integrals divided by the volume.

Comment: The limit of the divergence over $A_n$ is also 0. How would I go about showing that the value of this quotient actually converges to the divergence of $F$ at this point?

Comment: I do not understand your language. First, you mean the flux across the surface of the boundary of $A_n$ (which turns into the integral of the divergence over the volume $A_n$). Second, what in the world is an infinitely-dimensional function? All that's going on here is the definition of continuity. If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $A_n$ shrink down to $a$, then $f(a) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{A_n} f\,dV / \text{vol}(A_n)$.

Comment: You're asking how do you show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{B_\epsilon(x)} f(y) dV(y)}{\mathrm{vol}(B_\epsilon(x))}=f(x)$? An overkill answer is the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, though there are non-measure theoretic ways to show it too.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's not *totally* immediate from the definition of continuity because there is an interchange of limit and integral going on as well. But without fancy machinery you can, say, invoke uniform continuity on compacts and get the result.

Comment: @Ian Yes, exactly, I think that may question boils down to that. I thought of proving this by modeling $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{A_n} f(x) dx}{vol(A_n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{A_n} f(x) dx - \int_{\{x\}} f(x) dx}{vol(A_n) - vol(\{x\})}$, which would be the (handwavy) derivative of   $\int_{A_n} f(x) dx$, which is $f(x)$.

Comment: The rigorous way without any measure theory is to say that $f$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets, then given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $\delta>0$ so that if $\| y-x \|<\delta$ then $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Then $f(y)=f(x)+(f(y)-f(x))$, so $\int_{A_n} f(y) dV(y) = \int_{A_n} f(x) dV(y) + \int_{A_n} (f(y)-f(x)) dV(y)=f(x) \mathrm{vol}(A_n)$ plus a term which is bounded in magnitude by $\varepsilon \mathrm{vol}(A_n)$, provided the radius of $A_n$ is at most $\delta$. This issue of the radius going to zero alongside the volume is not actually automatic, it has to be assumed, as you did.

Comment: Thanks that already helps me a lot! Would the measure theoretic proof be more straightforward?

Comment: Not really, but it's basically "as general as it can be without being false", which means that it is often how mathematicians "prove" this kind of thing on the fly when they use it, if they bother to do so at all. (You'll notice that it was the first thing that I came up with, even though it's overkill for this context.)

Comment: It's no limit interchange. No uniform continuity needed. Just the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuity.

Comment: One more question though: How do we get from the the sequence of $A_n$ to the series of open balls centered at x? As far as I see it the sequence of of the above discussed quotient on the open balls is not necessarily a majorant of the sequence of the quotients on the $A_n$'s.

Comment: @multiplex You don't have to, you just need that $\sup_{y \in A_n} \| x-y\| \to 0$. But this is *not* automatic from the volume going to zero, it must be assumed separately.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right, the uniformity-in-y that you're using to say $|f(y)-f(x)|$ is small over the whole domain of integration is automatic from continuity, since the whole domain of integration is close to one point. (The result itself is still an interchange, though.)

Comment: @Ian That makes sense. In this case the fact that the limes superior of the distances from x is zero follows directly from the assumption that there is always an index from which on all further elements of the sequence $A_n$ are included in the open ball of x for any given diameter, right?

Comment: @Ian All I use is $|\int_A f|\le \int_A |f|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! In the end I think that I managed to form all your input into a concise proof.